# Auth fail : Running maven plugin with JGit

Tags: java, git, maven

I am facing this issue while building a maven project

```
[INFO] Cloning git@bitbucket.org:bookkeeper/bookkeeper-openapi3-hosted-ui-configuration.git:refs/tags/v5.0.0 into /Users/shubhamjain/bookkeeper/de/bookkeeper-ui-service/service/bookkeeper-api/bookkeeper-platform-hosted-ui-configuration-5.0.0
[ERROR] Failed to fetch bookkeeper-platform-hosted-ui-configuration API (5.0.0): 
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@bitbucket.org:bookkeeper/bookkeeper-openapi3-hosted-ui-configuration.git: Auth fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call (FetchCommand.java:222)
----
----
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@bitbucket.org:bookkeeper/bookkeeper-openapi3-hosted-ui-configuration.git: Auth fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession (JschConfigSessionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession (SshTransport.java:107)
```

Initially I had issues in access to the mentioned repository but then I got required permissions.

In the `pom.xml`

```
-----
-----
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.bookkeeper</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookkeeper-api-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-hosted-ui-configuration-openapi-hook</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate-client</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <apiName>bookkeeper-platform-hosted-ui-configuration</apiName>
                <apiVersion>5.0.0</apiVersion>
                <repositorySpecPath>bookkeeper-platform-hosted-ui-configuration/application-hosted-ui-configuration.yaml</repositorySpecPath>
                <gitUrlTemplate>git@bitbucket.org:bookkeeper/bookkeeper-openapi3-hosted-ui-configuration.git</gitUrlTemplate>
                <openapiConfigurationOverrides>
                    <isExperimental>false</isExperimental>
                    <apiName>hosted-ui-configuration</apiName>
                </openapiConfigurationOverrides>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
-----
-----
```

What could be missing ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was Maven couldn't find `ssh` binary path on the environment

Setting `GIT_SSH` environment variable worked.

```
export GIT_SSH=${SSH_BINARY_PATH}
```

In my case

```
export GIT_SSH=/usr/bin/ssh
```

Comment: Nitpick: it's ssh binary path, not ssh library path. :-)